# Two versions of enable_if usage work differently

Tags: c++, templates

I cannot understand why do two versions of copy constructor work differently (because of `enable_if`).

```
template <typename Type>
struct Predicate : std::integral_constant<bool, true>
{
};
template <>
struct Predicate<int> : std::integral_constant<bool, false>
{
};

template <typename FooType>
struct Settings
{
    Settings() {}

    //  Here it works fine
    template <typename OtherFooType>
    Settings(const Settings<OtherFooType>& other, std::enable_if_t<Predicate<OtherFooType>::value, int*> = 0) {}

    //  In this case enable_if does not work
    //template <typename OtherFooType>
    //Settings(typename std::enable_if<Predicate<OtherFooType>::value, const Settings<OtherFooType>&>::type other){}
};

int main()
{
    Settings<float> f = Settings<char>();
    return 0;
}
```

From my point of view, here `enable_if` is the SFINAE way to conditionally remove copy constructor. It should work in both cases. Maybe am I missing understaing of SFINAE?

Comment: The error message probably tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Better demo of problem: https://godbolt.org/z/91f8heYhq

Comment: @MarekR GCC's error message seems unfortunately not very helpful. Clang says explicitly what the issue is: https://godbolt.org/z/K66c7hWh6

Comment: @user17732522 I agree, I used msvc compiler, but it tells nothing helpful. Clang is more verbose about the issue

Comment: My aim with link was to give a hint how to provide nice Minimal Complete Reproducible Example. Just for the future questions. Yes in most cases clangs gives better error message. This was one of rationales to introduce new compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example the template parameter `OtherFooType` appears only left to the scope resolution operator `::` in the function parameter.

Everything left of `::` in a type specified by qualified name is a *non-deduced* context, meaning that the template argument for `OtherFooType` will not be deduced from the function parameter/argument pair.

As a consequence there is no way to deduce `OtherFooType` and so the constructor is always non-viable.

SFINAE doesn't even matter since that would be relevant only when substitution happens *after* successful deduction.

Also, (specializations of) constructor templates are never copy constructors. These are converting constructors and a copy constructor will still be declared implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will definitely reread book about c++ templates to better understand answer. It seems like my knowledge is a little bit rusty

Comment: It is more like problem is "dependent type" which can't be part of deduction.

Comment: @MarekR I'm not sure I understand? Every function parameter from which template arguments are deduced has also a dependent type, doesn't it?

Comment: Basically compiler doesn't know at this stage that `type` part is mapped from second template argument of `std::enable_if`. Note in general case this is not "one to one" relation. That is why standard says it can't be deduced.

Comment: @MarekR Yes that is the reason for the rule, but given `X<T>::type`, even if `X` is not partially/explicitly specialized and `type` is non-dependent in the primary template, `T` is still not deduced. The rule is wider and applies to all qualified type names.